# How do I make text unfold as website loads?

Tags: html, css

How do I make my text unfold (like on a typewriter) as my landing page loads?

Comment: Do you want something like this - [Typewriter Effect](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/typewriter-effect/)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could do it easily by adding a typing animation to your text.
I have added a sample code snippet and the reference. Feel free to play with it.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
}

@keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0 }
  to { width: 100% }
}

.typed-out{
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: .15em solid orange;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  width: 0;
  animation: typing 1s steps(20, end) forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="typed-out">NewFace12</div>
</div>
```

Reference: https://www.sitepoint.com/css-typewriter-effect/

Comment: Excellent Anshuman Yadav!

Comment: Please accept it as solution if it helps you. It will help others also.